# find a 6 digit number in String

Tags: java, regex

I've a String from a SMS like:

"Your code: 123456. Your reference number is 012. The total amount is E 1250,00.."

Now I need to extract the code '123456', which is different every time, but always 6 digits.

How can I extract this 6 digit number from the string? Can I use Regex expressions somehow? I need to be sure, so I don't want to split on 'code: ' for example.

EDIT:
The rest of the text can be different, but there will be only 6 digits in the SMS.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The regexpr for a 6 digit number is

```
\d{6}
```

Edit:
The code will look like

```
public static String extractDigits(final String in) {
   final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\\d{6})" );
   final Matcher m = p.matcher( in );
   if ( m.find() ) {
     return m.group( 0 );
   }
   return "";
 }
```

Comment: However, this will find 6 digits _anywhere in the input_

Comment: It the string you search in is fixed as the one above regexpr will by default find the first match

Comment: Only once there are 6 digits in the text, so this fixes my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if Java's Regex supports lookarounds. If it does:

```
(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
```

<sub>Edit: it does. (Thanks Bohemian)</sub>

Comment: Java does support look arounds

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `substring()`?

```
String s = "Your code: 123456. Your reference number is 012. The total amount is E 1250,00..";
String s2 = s.substring(11);
String code = s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf("."));
```

or just:

```
String code = s.substring(11, 17);
```

since it's always 6 digits.

Comment: I've edited my question. The rest of the text can be different (before or after), so that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String text = "125432";
   String regex = "\\D*\\d{6}\\D*";

   Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
   if(m.find())
      System.out.println(m.group(0).trim().substring(0,6));
```